# Changing default mail account while replying on specific messages while using few accounts on Mac Mail?

Tags: mac, apple-mail, reply

U use few mailboxes on my Mac Mail. When some emails come through specific account and I click REPLY it replies from a mailbox I don't want to use for this. How can I change a default account for replying for messages which come from a specific account? For example:

I have accounts pete@a1.com / pete@a2.com / pete@a3.com

Somehow (I believe I had to do it first time by accident and it remembered my choice), when a new message comes through pete@a1.com and I click REPLY button, it replies from pete@a2.com (instead of a1.com).

How to change that? It's annoying as I'm replying to my customers from my private mailbox, which I want to avoid.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You only have two choices...

- Reply from a specific account by default, or
- Reply using the currently selected mailbox.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that first message I sent to specific address is remembered. How to clean or change it? that may help? I believe I can't find this in options. Is there anything to edit in order to do that?

Comment: this is for new messages. I'm talking about responding to messages which come through specific account

Comment: It also works for replies. This is up to El Capitan, btw, I don't have Sierra.

Comment: I don't want to use the same account to reply on all messages. I just want to make sure I reply from the same account that message went through, so I used auto select. It works OK for the most cases but in case of this particular account it doesn't. I believe that if I can reset this somewhere it will work well. But there is no option. The system remembered my private account as a default reply for my business account and keep replying from it.

Comment: Then I can't figure out what you've done. Mine always replies from the account the email was sent to, even if I've re-filed to a different folder, outside the default mailbox.